# Prove $ | u(x) - u_h(x) | \leq h \ \underset{0 \leq y \leq 1}{\max} |u''(y)| $

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

Prove:

$ | u(x) - u_h(x) | \leq h \ \underset{0 \leq y \leq 1}{\max} |u''(y)| $

for $ 0 \leq x \leq 1 $

Using the fact that

$|| (u-u_h)'  || \leq \underset{0 \leq y \leq 1}{\max} |u''(y)|  $ and the boundary condition $ u(0) = u_h(0) = 0 $

the exercise also suggests

use the relation

$$ (u-u_h)(x) = \int_0^x (u-u_h)'(y) dy    $$ and the cauchy inequality

where

$$ || w || = (w,w)^{\frac{1}{2}} = ( \int_0^1 w^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}} dx  $$

I have tried to start with this:

I raise both sides squarely

$$ || (u-u_h)'  || = ( \int_0^1 (u-u_h)'^2 dx )^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

getting

$$ || (u-u_h)'  ||^2 = | \int_0^1 (u-u_h)'^2 dx | $$

and then reached a dead end

Comment: What is $u_h(x)$?

Comment: $u$ is the analytical solution to a pde problem, and $ u_h(x) $ is the solution of a finite element problem associated with the same pde

Comment: I imagine that knowing the exact PDE as well as the equation satisfied by the approximation would be helpful when searching for any relation between them.

Comment: I guess not, beacause $u$ is a general solution as $ u_h $ and i guess that is not the way to go. For me its just algebraic work, that i cannot do it btw. But i will give a look from that perspective as well

Comment: I guess $u_h$ comes from using linear finite elements, correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct